# How to set all global variables in a Fortran module to private for OpenMP?

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp, default, private

I would like to know how can I set global variables in a Fortran module which I call in an `omp parallel` section. I know `THREADPRIVATE` can set a list of variables to private, but I have too many global variables to set. Is there a way to change the default to private for the global variables?

Comment: Sounds like a terrible design, and an easy way to get yourself into ages of debugging. It's probably easier to refactor the code first and parallelize it later.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such way (as far as I am aware of). Use `threadprivate` and list all the variables you need. If you have too many global variables, get rid of them. They are not a sign of good code design.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am thinking what I can do if the module is a library and I can not change it.

Comment: You can do very little. You should change the library. Or avoid the global variables of that library.

Comment: From a simple test it seems that Intel Fortran let's you to put `threadprivate` in the code that uses the module. Gfortran does not allow that. I am not sure which is correct.

Comment: Do you think openMPI will be suitable for this case?

Comment: OpenMPI is an implementation of MPI. That is something **completely** different from OpenMP. If you don't know what MPI is, forget it.